# How can i connect to a OpenCMS server using his API

Tags: java, opencms

Can i connect to my OpenCMS from a Java standalone using the OpenCMS API? Thanks

Comment: i have a problem using the OpenCMS API outside a jsp. I need a remote connection to get things like list of used types ids, state of server, schedule publish, ...

Comment: Please move this comment in your question so your question get more visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=connect%20to%20opencms%20using%20opencms%20api%20filetype%3Ajava&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.docjar.com%2Fsrc%2Fapi%2Fcom%2Fopencms%2Fboot%2FCmsSetupDb.java&ei=xC5MUZidKdH07Aa95YGADA&usg=AFQjCNHx50f3My0Z-36dj4rdOvDLO_uY7g) You can find a File which is a small but complete project which is configured with JDBC used by OpenCMS.
You can also find its detailed Githu repository [here](http://www.opencms.org/en/development/revision-control.html).And also see [this small application provided by opencms on thier repository](http://code.google.com/p/opencms-backoffice/source/browse/branches/test-red5/playlist/src/org/red5/webapps/red5java/Application.java?r=166)
I am not the one who down voted you but please consider that this forum is only for problem solving.But not for the things like Homeworks.Please take care next time.Goodluck :)

Comment: Its not homework, its opencms coorporative maintenance and i have a problem using the OpenCMS API outside a jsp. I need a remote connection to get things like list of used types ids, state of server, schedule publish, ...

You give me a noob example of dababase connect but thanks anyway.

Comment: I would click your answer as useful but someone get my reputation down with this question (i need 15)

Comment: but you can accept my answer if it is useful for you.Please always accept those answers which help you